# Pig - HBASE Query - Dynamic Columns - Convert Map to Bag

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-pig

I am attempting to use Pig to query a HBASE table where the table columns are dynamic (column titles not known at query time). Thus this makes referencing the map[] of key values returned not feasible. I would like to convert each map returned by the query into a bag of key-value tuples.

How do I do this?

I have seen one example that seems to rank high in search results (in python) that converts each map key-value pair into a bag of tuples. See below.

```
@outputSchema("values:bag{t:tuple(key, value)}")
def bag_of_tuples(map_dict):
    return map_dict.items()
```

However, in trying to follow this example, I do not know where the .items() function is coming from. Is there a way do achieve this in pure Pig Latin with out-of-the-box UDFs?